# Convert RasterStack object to Array and Array to RasterStack

Tags: raster, r, array

I have a RasterStack object. I need to convert it into an array and then convert this array into a new RasterStack.

```
library(raster)
```

Here a RasterStack example:

```
m <- raster(ncol=10, nrow=10)
values(m) <- 1:100
r <- stack(m, m, m)
```

I'm able to convert the RasterStack into an array using:

```
arr <- as.array(r)
dim(arr)
```

**[1] 10 10  3**

How can I convert the `arr` array into a new RasterStack object?

Comment: Typo in your first example? `values(r) <- 1:100` should be `values(m) <- 1:100`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`brick(arr)` will get you a brick, which is close enough to a stack for most purposes, but you can do `stack(brick(arr))` if you really need a stack:

```
> stack(brick(arr))
class       : RasterStack 
dimensions  : 10, 10, 100, 3  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution  : 0.1, 0.1  (x, y)
extent      : 0, 1, 0, 1  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : NA 
names       : layer.1, layer.2, layer.3 
min values  :       1,       1,       1 
max values  :     100,     100,     100
```

Note this round trip (stack -> array -> stack) loses the lat-long and other coordinate system values. You can peel them off the original and paste back on the new stack if you need.

Comment: Great! The intermediate step by `brick()` fixes everything. The purpose of converting the raster to array is to feed a Deep Learning model using Tensorflow-Keras in R, so after performing the inference I will have to paste the properties of the initial RasterStack.

Comment: Oh I forgot to add the obligatory "You should look at using the `terra` package in place of the `raster` package now" message (faster, maintained, better functionality etc)